# How can i bind my media player activity with existing media player service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, message-passing, android-service-binding

I know similar kind of question has been asked before, but none of them are helping me. I am building a music player in which I want to connect my Music through my music player like play, pause etc. Currently, media player service is connected with playlist activity but I have custom designed my media player and I am not able to connect it to the service class.

my MusicPlayer Activity is like this:

```
public class MusicPlayer extends AppCompatActivity implements PlaylistFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

public static final String Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.PlayNewAudio";

ImageView buttonPlayToggle;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

MediaPlayerService player;
boolean serviceBound = false;

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

        MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
        player = binder.getService();
        serviceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Music Player");


    buttonPlayToggle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_play_toggle);

    buttonPlayToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mediaPlayer == null) return;

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                updatePlayToggle(true);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                updatePlayToggle(false);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

        }

    });

    if (!serviceBound) {

        Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        startService(playerIntent);
        bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {


        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

}

public void updatePlayToggle(boolean play) {
    buttonPlayToggle.setImageResource(play ? R.drawable.ic_pause : R.drawable.ic_play);
}
```

My ServicecClass is like this:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,

    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.ACTION_PLAY";
public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.ACTION_PAUSE";
public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.ACTION_PREVIOUS";
public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.ACTION_NEXT";
public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.ACTION_STOP";

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager;
private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

//Used to pause/resume MediaPlayer
private int resumePosition;

//AudioFocus
private AudioManager audioManager;

// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();

private ArrayList<Audio> audioList;
private int audioIndex = -1;
private Audio activeAudio; //an object on the currently playing audio


//Handle incoming phone calls
private boolean ongoingCall = false;
private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;


/**
 * Service lifecycle methods
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return iBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    callStateListener();
    //ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY -- change in audio outputs -- BroadcastReceiver
    registerBecomingNoisyReceiver();
    //Listen for new Audio to play -- BroadcastReceiver
    register_playNewAudio();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {

        //Load data from SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        audioList = storage.loadAudio();
        audioIndex = storage.loadAudioIndex();

        if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
            //index is in a valid range
            activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    //Request audio focus
    if (!requestAudioFocus()) {
        //Could not gain focus
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mediaSessionManager == null) {
        try {
            initMediaSession();
            initMediaPlayer();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
    }

    //Handle Intent action from MediaSession.TransportControls
    handleIncomingActions(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    mediaSession.release();
    removeNotification();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        stopMedia();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    removeAudioFocus();
    //Disable the PhoneStateListener
    if (phoneStateListener != null) {
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

    removeNotification();

    //unregister BroadcastReceivers
    unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(playNewAudio);

    //clear cached playlist
    new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).clearCachedAudioPlaylist();
}

/**
 * Service Binder
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MediaPlayerService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return MediaPlayerService.this;
    }
}


/**
 * MediaPlayer callback methods
 */
@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    //Invoked indicating buffering status of
    //a media resource being streamed over the network.
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Invoked when playback of a media source has completed.
    stopMedia();

    removeNotification();
    //stop the service
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    //Invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation
    switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    //Invoked to communicate some info
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Invoked when the media source is ready for playback.
    playMedia();
}

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Invoked indicating the completion of a seek operation.
}

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusState) {

    //Invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.
    switch (focusState) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            // resume playback
            if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer();
            else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
            // at an attenuated level
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            break;
    }
}


/**
 * AudioFocus
 */
private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        //Focus gained
        return true;
    }
    //Could not gain focus
    return false;
}

private boolean removeAudioFocus() {
    return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
            audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
}


/**
 * MediaPlayer actions
 */
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();//new MediaPlayer instance

    //Set up MediaPlayer event listeners
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
    mediaPlayer.reset();


    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        // Set the data source to the mediaFile location
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio.getLocalData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}

private void playMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

private void stopMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) return;
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

private void pauseMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        resumePosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}

private void resumeMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(resumePosition);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

private void skipToNext() {

    if (audioIndex == audioList.size() - 1) {
        //if last in playlist
        audioIndex = 0;
        activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
    } else {
        //get next in playlist
        activeAudio = audioList.get(++audioIndex);
    }

    //Update stored index
    new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

    stopMedia();
    //reset mediaPlayer
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    initMediaPlayer();
}

private void skipToPrevious() {

    if (audioIndex == 0) {
        //if first in playlist
        //set index to the last of audioList
        audioIndex = audioList.size() - 1;
        activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
    } else {
        //get previous in playlist
        activeAudio = audioList.get(--audioIndex);
    }

    //Update stored index
    new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

    stopMedia();
    //reset mediaPlayer
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    initMediaPlayer();
}


/**
 * ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY -- change in audio outputs
 */
private BroadcastReceiver becomingNoisyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //pause audio on ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
        pauseMedia();
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
    }
};

private void registerBecomingNoisyReceiver() {
    //register after getting audio focus
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
    registerReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver, intentFilter);
}

/**
 * Handle PhoneState changes
 */
private void callStateListener() {
    // Get the telephony manager
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //Starting listening for PhoneState changes
    phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                //if at least one call exists or the phone is ringing
                //pause the MediaPlayer
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        pauseMedia();
                        ongoingCall = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    // Phone idle. Start playing.
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (ongoingCall) {
                            ongoingCall = false;
                            resumeMedia();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    // Register the listener with the telephony manager
    // Listen for changes to the device call state.
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

/**
 * MediaSession and Notification actions
 */
private void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
    if (mediaSessionManager != null) return; //mediaSessionManager exists

    mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
    // Create a new MediaSession
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "AudioPlayer");
    //Get MediaSessions transport controls
    transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
    //set MediaSession -> ready to receive media commands
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    //indicate that the MediaSession handles transport control commands
    // through its MediaSessionCompat.Callback.
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    //Set mediaSession's MetaData
    updateMetaData();

    // Attach Callback to receive MediaSession updates
    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        // Implement callbacks
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();

            resumeMedia();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            pauseMedia();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            super.onSkipToNext();

            skipToNext();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            super.onSkipToPrevious();

            skipToPrevious();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            removeNotification();
            //Stop the service
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long position) {
            super.onSeekTo(position);
        }
    });
}

private void updateMetaData() {
    mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, activeAudio.getLocalArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, activeAudio.getLocalAlbum())
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, activeAudio.getLocalTitle())
            .build());
}

private void buildNotification(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus) {


    int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;//needs to be initialized
    PendingIntent play_pauseAction = null;

    //Build a new notification according to the current state of the MediaPlayer
    if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
        //create the pause action
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(1);
    } else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
        //create the play action
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(0);
    }


    // Create a new Notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Hide the timestamp
            .setShowWhen(false)
            // Set the Notification style
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    // Attach our MediaSession token
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    // Show our playback controls in the compat view
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            // Set the Notification color
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            // Set the large and small icons
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            // Set Notification content information
            .setContentText(activeAudio.getLocalArtist())
            .setContentTitle(activeAudio.getLocalAlbum())
            .setContentInfo(activeAudio.getLocalTitle())
            // Add playback actions
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "next", playbackAction(2));

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}


private PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber) {
    Intent playbackAction = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
    switch (actionNumber) {
        case 0:
            // Play
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 1:
            // Pause
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 2:
            // Next track
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 3:
            // Previous track
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

private void removeNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

private void handleIncomingActions(Intent playbackAction) {
    if (playbackAction == null || playbackAction.getAction() == null) return;

    String actionString = playbackAction.getAction();
    if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        transportControls.play();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
        transportControls.pause();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_NEXT)) {
        transportControls.skipToNext();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PREVIOUS)) {
        transportControls.skipToPrevious();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) {
        transportControls.stop();
    }
}


/**
 * Play new Audio
 */
private BroadcastReceiver playNewAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Get the new media index form SharedPreferences
        audioIndex = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).loadAudioIndex();
        if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
            //index is in a valid range
            activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }

        //A PLAY_NEW_AUDIO action received
        //reset mediaPlayer to play the new Audio
        stopMedia();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        initMediaPlayer();
        updateMetaData();
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
    }
};

private void register_playNewAudio() {
    //Register playNewMedia receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(FragmentRight.Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
    registerReceiver(playNewAudio, filter);
}
```

And my Playlist fragment is like this:

```
public class FragmentRight extends Fragment {

public static final String Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO = "com.example.anuj.musicmetest.PlayNewAudio";

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

ArrayList<Audio> localList;

TextView nameView;

private MediaPlayerService mediaPlayer;
boolean serviceBound = false;

public FragmentRight() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_right, container, false);

    nameView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name1);

    loadAudio();

    RecyclerView recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
    LocalListAdapter localListAdapteradapter = new LocalListAdapter(getActivity().getApplication(), localList);
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(localListAdapteradapter);
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplication()));
    recyclerView1.addOnItemTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener(getActivity(), new onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int index) {
            playAudio(index);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlayer.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }));


    return rootView;
}

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
        mediaPlayer = binder.getService();
        serviceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};

private void playAudio(int audioIndex) {
    //Check is service is active
    if (!serviceBound) {
        //Store Serializable audioList to SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudio(localList);
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        Intent playerIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MediaPlayerService.class);
        getActivity().startService(playerIntent);
        getActivity().bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {
        //Store the new audioIndex to SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);


        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}

private void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        localList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String localData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String localTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String localAlbum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String localArtist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

            // Save to audioList
            localList.add(new Audio(localData, localTitle, localAlbum, localArtist));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}



// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (serviceBound) {
        getContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);
        //service is active
        mediaPlayer.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using the [recommended pattern for an audio playing app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html)?

Comment: ya, I want to build my app without using mediabrowserservice. I thought it will not be a big challenge. But now I am stuck

Comment: Well I have implemented some code on this would you please try to get reference from my code https://github.com/dushyant30suthar/Music ?

Comment: this is more or less I have already implemented. Connecting fragment with service is not an issue. The issue is once the song starts playing from fragment I want to bring my music player into the action, so I want to get the playing status of media player from service class. How can I do that?